# fatal error , when try to compile a C programing code?

Tags: shell, terminal, compiling, c

i am a beginner in ubuntu os.
In the terminal box, i try to run a simple C programing code using Visual Studio, and it shows me  ***

> fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory

---

that kind of error.
So, what should i do to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 3):

This header file is from old MS-DOS dev interface. You can replace it (almost) with `curses.h`. For more details you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792443/2908599).

> `conio.h` is a C header file used in old MS-DOS compilers to create text
>   user interfaces. Compilers that targeted non-DOS operating systems,
>   such as Linux, Win32 and OS/2, provided different implementations of
>   these functions.
>
> The `#include <curses.h>` will give you almost all the functionalities
>   that was provided in `conio.h`
>
> nucurses need to be installed at the first place
>
> In deb based Distros use
>
> `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`

Comment: thank you sir :)

Comment: @suvasishdas, if you are happy with my answer feel free to accept it and/or upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

What you do is should stop trying to write MS/PC-DOS programs.  You are using a completely different operating system.

`conio.h` is one of the headers that comprises the C language bindings to the DOS API.  Programs that employ it are MS/PC-DOS programs.

People will tell you that curses "does the same thing".  It actually really does not, as the DOS console API has quite a different paradigm to full-screen TUIs built on POSIX terminal I/O.  Porting from one to the other is *not* as simple as a header file change.  (There were compatibility headers in compilers for OS/2 and Windows NT, because those operating systems have "console" I/O paradigms that map far better to the DOS console API.)  And that's not yet accounting for the fact that there were two flavours of console API as employed in old DOS code, Borland/Watcom and Microsoft.

The *right* change is to simply forget about the DOS API from 30 years ago, and write a program that uses your actual operating system's APIs: POSIX terminal I/O with your choice of TUI library, X11 with your choice of toolkit, or whatever.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2010). *[The gen on the C and C++ language bindings to the DOS API](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dos-api-bindings.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558840/5132

Comment: Thank You Sir :)